# Partition edges into areas

Tags: algorithms, graph

If I have a series of edges that branch and curve, such as in a road network, is there an algorithm that will identify the areas (defined by sequence of geographic points) defined between those lines?

e.g.

From

[image: road network]

to

[image: partitioned road network areas]

Keeping in mind that the areas can be irregular shapes.

Comment: There are several ways to approach this problem. I think you should provide more detail to assist people looking to answer the question. In particular: **1.** What format are the lines/edges stored in? (e.g. is it x, y coordinates for start and end points). **2.** Is the algorithm run *on-the-fly* or is it pre-computing values that are looked up at a later date? **3.** Do the polygons ever overlap? Are there other complications such as margins of error for the line/edge vertices?

Comment: If input is bitmap, use [connected component labeling](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gac2718a64ade63475425558aa669a943a). If input is geometry (vertices), see [combinatorial map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_map). If already using a GIS system, see [map algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_algebra) or the documentation of the system.

Comment: It is likely that your question has already been asked before and answered on the [GIS site (gis.stackexchange.com)](http://gis.stackexchange.com/). If you are using a GIS software, you should be able to get the information easily without implementing your own algorithms. If you are not using a GIS software, it could be difficult, and your question currently did not provide enough detail (see Peter Tòmas Scott's comment) for anyone to write an answer. If you are a software consultant (i.e. you do not plan to implement it yourself), the answer would be "use a GIS software".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a "Polygonizer". Unfortunately, the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygonizer) is currently just a stub, but you can google for this term, which leads you to some free and some commercial implementations.